# Visual Studio 2010 - Database Projects (where are the project template for just script files?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

VS.NET 2010 **removed** the database project template that could be used for just script files 
(that you right click on and execute on desired database).

I want to add a database project similar to the ones in VS.NET 2008? Can i do this?

I tried to use one of the new vs.net 2010 database projects however, in our environment we have multiple applications within the same database.  We also have a lot of legacy stuff.  In addition we have a lot of queries that cross databases (i.e. in the case of accessing data wharehouse tables).  It sure seems that this scenario is hard to use with the new database projects. It seems this adds a lot of complexity to using the new db projects.

What sort of database project is best to be used for this scenario??